# Update database field SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have tried many things, with no result. My question is, as the title says, how do I update a field in a database using SQL? Since I am a beginner with coding and SQL, I will copy my whole code below, not knowing what information you may need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using HPJFRMS;

namespace HPJFRMS
{
    public partial class HomeFRM : Form
    {
        private string conn;
        MySqlConnection connect;
        string _naam = "";
        Form _Loginfrm;

        public HomeFRM(Form logFrom, string _name)
        {
            _Loginfrm = logFrom;
            InitializeComponent();
            lbWelkom.Text = "welkom " + _name;
            _naam = _name;
        }

        private void HomeFRM_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmCheck.Enabled = true;
        }

        private bool Todo_ophalen()
        {
            db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmdRead = new MySqlCommand();
            cmdRead.CommandText = "SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
            cmdRead.Connection = connect;
            MySqlDataReader tdOphalen = cmdRead.ExecuteReader();
            if (tdOphalen.Read())
            {
                tbTodo.Text = tdOphalen.GetString(0);
                connect.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                connect.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        private void btBewerk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btBewerk.Text == "Bewerken")
            {
                tbTodo.ReadOnly = false;
                btBewerk.Text = "Opslaan";
                tmCheck.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                /* HERE COMES THE "UPDATE" CODE */
            }
        }

        private void tmCheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bool T = Todo_ophalen();
                if (T)
                {
                    lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lbStatus.Text = "Online";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lbStatus.Text = "Offline";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of guides on how to update rows in an SQL database using C#. Follow one of these guides and if you have a problem getting it to work then post a question about that specific problem. It's unlikely that anyone will just write the code for you, that's not what the community is for. You should also look at parameterized queries, your code is vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Something tells me this is clearly just some school assignment. You could go ahead with the answers given below, but you clearly still lack the skills to understand what is going on. 

I guess you are better off not being able to complete this assignment (which is fine) instead of using other people their code not knowing what is going on and giving the impression you understand your subject.

Comment: @Jens No, it is not for school. It is for my internship, where i have to make a tool which will only be used by us. Do i look so much like a beginner? i tried to hide it :3 . Anyway, by repeating codes i find here (own and others questions), i am able to learn it faster than just ctrl-c and ctrl-v -ing. I wrote a update code al by myself today! such an achievement. Anyway, thank you for you concerns! (but dont worry, i got this ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods, you can use any of these.

Method 1: using simple SQL query

```
public void Update(Int UserId,String UserName  )
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");  
    con.Open();  
    string str = " UPDATE [dbo].[User] SET [UserName] = "+UserName  +" WHERE   [UserId] ="+ UserId+"";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str , con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Method 2: using a stored procedure

First execute your stored procedure in database.

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUser]   
    @UserId int,   
    @UserName varchar(25)   
AS   
BEGIN   
    UPDATE [dbo].[User] 
    SET [UserName] = @UserName 
    WHERE [UserId] = @UserId   
END   

public void Update(Int UserId,String UserName  )
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");  
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateUser", con); //UpdateUser is the name of stored procedure you created
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName ", UserName );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", UserId);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample method for an update:

```
public void UpdateUser(User userToUpdate)
{
    try
    {
        string sqlStatement = @"UPDATE USERS " +
                               "SET DisplayName = @DisplayName, Username = @Username" +
                               "WHERE Id = @Id";

        using (SqlConnectionconn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", userToUpdate.Id));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisplayName", userToUpdate.DisplayName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userToUpdate.UserName));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (DbException ex)
    {
        throw ExceptionHandler.CreateSystemException(ex, ErrorStrings.DATABASE_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This should get you started but you really need to read up on this subject as explaining the correct practices would be too long for an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

this is maybe you need

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
try 
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(con);
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE table_name SET field_name_1 = ?param1, field_name_2 = ?param2 WHERE id = ?id";

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param1", value1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?param2", value2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", value3);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
catch (MySqlException ee)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: this is in the mysql, if you are using mssql change mark ? with @

Comment: you should consider using ADO.net Entity data model to help you faster in coding.